# Tabs get dynamically added,how to settext to it

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs

```
package com.agri.kishan;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.agri.kishan.OneFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.agri.kishan.OneFragment;

public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int tabsele;
    public static String realqus="this is a sample qus";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);
        //

        //
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tab.getPosition()+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 tabsele=tab.getPosition();
                /////////////////////////////////////////
                /////////////////////////////////
                ///////////////////
```

**I want to set text according to the position,I get position successfully**

```
                if(tabsele==0)
                {
                   OneFragment.tv.setText("hai");



                } else if(tabsele==1)
                {
                    OneFragment.tv.setText("bye");
                }
                //////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////
                ///////////////////////////////////////////



            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for(int i=0;i<=Card_display.counttabs;i++) {
            adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "Qus:"+i);
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

> Fragment page
>   the fragment page is a simple fragment page which has an text view in it,
>   i get the postion of the tab from activity
>   i want to change the text to the textview in the fragment according to the position from the activity

**Fragement page**
    package com.agri.kishan;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.agri.kishan.ScrollableTabsActivity;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    /////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////
    //////////////////
   public static TextView  tv;
    ////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////
    /////////////////////

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,
                container, false);


        tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.realqus);



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }


}
```

Comment: form Activity how to get the view of fragement so that i can set text in fragement plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach
Inside your `onTabSelected`

```
  OneFragment page = (OneFragment)viewPager.getAdapter().getItem(tab.getPosition());
page.tv.setText("Hi");
```

Comment: no its not working and Viewpager.getCurrentItem() dint work so i used tabs.getPosition replacing it....but also it dint work plllllzzz help

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: for OneFragment page = (OneFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                    page.tv.setText("Hi"); i used OneFragment page = (OneFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + tab.getPosition());
                    page.tv.setText("Hi");
i dont get any error but textciew dows not change

Comment: make the textView tv  not static and try again

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ,what is the text that is shown in the screen?

Comment: <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text=" Is java a power full language?"
                android:id="@+id/realqus"
                android:padding="5dp" /> is java a power fulll language is displaying

Comment: OneFragment page = (OneFragment)viewPager.getAdapter().getItem(tab.getPosition());
                page.tv.setText("Hi");-----------getItem is an error red in color